# How to group node comments using parent comment in views

Tags: comments, views

I have a content type that student users can comment on. Tutors can go to each comment and respond with an answer.

On each node, I want to display the comments a user makes ONLY. Each comment should be a thread though, showing the responses from tutors.

Right now I have tried views and seen the potential to use a parent comment as relationship then filtering on the parent comment's uid. This however, doesn't bring out the needed functionality.

How do you think I can accomplish this. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, maybe this way:

1. Create Views that view only comments. and filter from all comments only those, that was made by the users with role "student".
2. With [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module mark-up displaying of your content type - "screw" this view to your content type.
3. Edit what view that is checked id of this node and show comments only for this node